# "require" em diretórios superiores

Tags: lua

Tenho um programa em Lua. Essa é a estrutura dos arquivos:

```
|Programa
|-Main.lua
|-config.lua
|--------functions
                  |-functions.lua
```

Através do `functions.lua`, eu quero dar um `require` no `config.lua`. Tem algum jeito?

Já tentei:

```
require "../config"
require "..\\config"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes do `require` você deve *setar* o *path* do pacote, dizer em que arquivos deve procurar pelo módulo:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";../config.lua"
require "config"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Path.lua).

Note que a utilização é parecida com o que se faz com *path* de sistemas operacionais. Você adiciona um novo *path* ao que já existe para não perder os demais.

Comment: Não funcionou, agora nos erros também mostra: no file '../luafunctions.lua'

Comment: E o que aparecia antes?

Comment: A mesma mensagem(no file), só que sem esse diretorio.

Comment: tente assim: `package.path = package.path .. ";../?.lua"`. Imprime o `package.path` e veja se ele está sendo formado corretamente.

Comment: Retornou: ./?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;../?.lua

Comment: É, não faço ideia, na minha curta experiência nunca vi isso acontecer.